# Rstudio: Apply a formula/argument to all rows of an r object

Tags: r, function, loops, apply

After trying many ways, i am coming here to ask a question regarding Rstudio.

Basically, i have an R object named **'dates'** with 42264 obs. of 1 variable (These are all dates, format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS, that i created through the package lubridate). I have another R object named **'observation'** of 274 obs. of 2 variables (Also dates in the same format, the first column is named **'Start'** and the second is named **'End'**, because they represent a time range). What i would like to do, is exclude from the object 'dates', all dates that are found within the time periods in 'observation'. I found the following argument which seems to work fine (kind of):

```
nouvelles_dates<-dates[!(dates$Date %in% observation$Start:observation$End),]
```

However, my issue is that this argument only applies to the first row (time period) in 'observation', while I want it to be applied to all 274 rows.

I get the following error message :

```
#Error in 1:observation : NA/NaN argument
#In addition: Warning messages:
#1: In observation$Start:observation$End :
#  numerical expression has 274 elements: only the first used
```

I tried creating loops so the argument would be applied to all rows in 'observation', I tried through the argument for() and apply() but they don't seem to work. Maybe it's my fault applying the argument badly. Do you have any ideas on how I can solve this?

subsample of my data:
object 'dates':

```
A tibble: 42,264 x 1 
Date <dttm> 
1 2018-05-29 08:00:00 
2 2018-05-29 08:01:00 
3 2018-05-29 08:02:00 
4 2018-05-29 08:03:00 
5 2018-05-29 08:04:00 
6 2018-05-29 08:05:00 
# ... with 42,258 more rows
```

object 'observation'

```
A tibble: 274 x 2 
Start End 
<dttm> <dttm> 
1 2018-05-29 16:56:00 2018-05-29 18:16:00 
2 2018-05-30 15:37:00 2018-05-30 16:57:00 
3 2018-05-31 03:07:00 2018-05-31 04:27:00 
# ... with 271 more rows
```

Comment: Hi, can you share a subsample of your data so it more easier to give you an appropriate answer

Comment: Hello. Thank you! 
object 'dates':
 A tibble: 42,264 x 1
   Date               
   <dttm>             
 1 2018-05-29 08:00:00
 2 2018-05-29 08:01:00
 3 2018-05-29 08:02:00
 4 2018-05-29 08:03:00
 5 2018-05-29 08:04:00
 6 2018-05-29 08:05:00
# ... with 42,258 more rows

object 'observation'
A tibble: 274 x 2
Start               End                
   <dttm>              <dttm>           
 1 2018-05-29 16:56:00 2018-05-29 18:16:00
 2 2018-05-30 15:37:00 2018-05-30 16:57:00
 3 2018-05-31 03:07:00 2018-05-31 04:27:00
# ... with 271 more rows

Answer (score 0):

Try this... hoping I have understood your question correctly.

```
observation_dates <- c(observations$Start, observations$End)

required_rows <- dates[which(!dates$Date %in% observation_dates),]
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer. Actually, what i want is that the object 'dates' in the end won't contain any date found between the different time periods in the object 'observation'. For example to remove all dates between 2018-05-29 16:56:00 2018-05-29 18:16:00, also all dates between 2018-05-30 15:37:00 2018-05-30 16:57:00 and so on for all 274 time periods (rows).
this : observation_dates <- c(observations$Start, observations$End) only assembles dates in one dataframe but not as time periods. So 'required_rows' doesn't remove dates found in time frames.  hope i explained it correctly..